# get the month name in words in jtable display format dd-mm-yy

Tags: jquery, jquery-jtable

I am having a situation here, in Jtable i have a field with display format dd-mm-yy and it displays like this

```
05-08-2014
```

but i want to display only the month name like this

```
August
```

what change should i do in this code(this is a field in jtable)

```
Month:{                                                     
    type: 'date',
    displayFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    Weightage: 1,
    required: true,                              
    title: 'Month'                          
},
```

Comment: Not sure, but give `displayFormat: 'dd-MM-yy'` a try

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
   displayFormat: 'MM',
```

or,use `moment.js`

```
     display: function (data) {
               return moment(data.record.Month).format('MMMM');  //Specfiy Date root Path.
               }
```

instead of using `displayFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'`

[Check this link](http://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

```
(function month(m) {
  $.each(["January", "February", "March", "April"
         , "May", "June", "July", "August"
         , "September", "October", "November", "December"]
         , function (k, v) {
             if (new RegExp(v.slice(0, 3)).test(new Date())) {
               m = v;
             };
  });
  return m
}(""));
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/Y62kq/